# problem with sql syntax

Tags: sql, oracle

The sql syntax is following:

```
SELECT y.NAME, y.EMAIL, k.DATE, k.WORK_NR, k.SCORE, k.FILENAME
FROM bas1.students y, bas1.assignments k, bas1.topics a
WHERE y.ID = k.student_id AND k.topic_id = a.id
WHERE a.NAME = 'History';
```

But I get some errors, any Ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're  using WHERE twice

```
SELECT y.NAME, y.EMAIL, k.DATE, k.WORK_NR, k.SCORE, k.FILENAME
FROM bas1.students y, bas1.assignments k, bas1.topics a
WHERE y.ID = k.student_id AND k.topic_id = a.id
AND a.NAME = 'History';
```

change to this

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need join statements?  E.g.,

```
SELECT y.NAME, y.EMAIL, k.DATE, k.WORK_NR, k.SCORE, k.FILENAME
FROM bas1.students y JOIN bas1.assignments k ON y.ID = k.student_id 
JOIN bas1.topics a ON k.topic_id = a.id
WHERE a.NAME = 'History';
```