# # in access sql not accepted

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have just started learning sql, and I have a ms access database with # symbols in column names, for example the check# column to keep track from the checks i have written out.

So when I use the sql statement `SELECT check# FROM checks;` it says that something is wrong with the syntax and you can't make such a query.

I want to thank in advance for stackoverflow and all its members.

Comment: Advise not to use spaces or punctuation/special characters (underscore is only exception) in naming convention.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [problem with sql syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318994/problem-with-sql-syntax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try escaping the column name using square bracket `[]` like below

```
SELECT [check#] FROM checks;
```

(OR) using double quotes `""` like

```
SELECT "check#" FROM checks;
```

Comment: Quotes won't work in Access, it will just return the constant string `"check#"` for all rows. Square brackets work.